# cakephp2 how to always show jump link paginator first and last regardless which page currently

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

I have this code

```
<div class="paging">
<?php
    echo $this->Paginator->first('<<', array('class' => 'first'));
    echo $this->Paginator->prev('<', array(), null, array('class' => 'prev disabled'));
    echo '<span class="numbers">';
    echo $this->Paginator->numbers();
    echo '</span>';
    echo $this->Paginator->next('>', array(), null, array('class' => 'next disabled'));
    echo $this->Paginator->last('>>', array('class' => 'last'));
?>
</div>
```

but the problem is, if I'm in the first page the '<<' link will not show up. I think it's by cakephp design it is like this. Is there anyway to show the jump link both first and last page, eventhough I'm in the first or last page?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by extends Paginator view Helper class.

Create the file `PaginatorExtHelper.php` in your `View/Helper/` folder as below.

```
<?php
App::uses('PaginatorHelper', 'View/Helper');

class PaginatorExtHelper extends PaginatorHelper {

    public function first($first = '<< first', $options = array()) {
        $options = array_merge(
            array(
                'tag' => 'span',
                'after' => null,
                'model' => $this->defaultModel(),
                'separator' => ' | ',
                'ellipsis' => '...',
                'class' => null
            ),
        (array)$options);

        $params = array_merge(array('page' => 1), (array)$this->params($options['model']));
        unset($options['model']);

        if ($params['pageCount'] <= 1) {
            return false;
        }
        extract($options);
        unset($options['tag'], $options['after'], $options['model'], $options['separator'], $options['ellipsis'], $options['class']);

        $out = '';

        if (is_int($first) && $params['page'] >= $first) {
            if ($after === null) {
                $after = $ellipsis;
            }
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $first; $i++) {
                $out .= $this->Html->tag($tag, $this->link($i, array('page' => $i), $options), compact('class'));
                if ($i != $first) {
                    $out .= $separator;
                }
            }
            $out .= $after;
        } elseif ($params['page'] >= 1 && is_string($first)) {
            $options += array('rel' => 'first');
            if($params['page'] == 1){
                $out = $this->Html->tag($tag, $first, compact('class')) . $after;
            }else{
                $out = $this->Html->tag($tag, $this->link($first, array('page' => 1), $options), compact('class')) . $after;
            }
        }
        return $out;
    }

    public function last($last = 'last >>', $options = array()) {
        $options = array_merge(
            array(
                'tag' => 'span',
                'before' => null,
                'model' => $this->defaultModel(),
                'separator' => ' | ',
                'ellipsis' => '...',
                'class' => null
            ),
        (array)$options);

        $params = array_merge(array('page' => 1), (array)$this->params($options['model']));
        unset($options['model']);

        if ($params['pageCount'] <= 1) {
            return false;
        }

        extract($options);
        unset($options['tag'], $options['before'], $options['model'], $options['separator'], $options['ellipsis'], $options['class']);

        $out = '';
        $lower = $params['pageCount'] - $last + 1;

        if (is_int($last) && $params['page'] <= $lower) {
            if ($before === null) {
                $before = $ellipsis;
            }
            for ($i = $lower; $i <= $params['pageCount']; $i++) {
                $out .= $this->Html->tag($tag, $this->link($i, array('page' => $i), $options), compact('class'));
                if ($i != $params['pageCount']) {
                    $out .= $separator;
                }
            }
            $out = $before . $out;
        } elseif ($params['page'] <= $params['pageCount'] && is_string($last)) {
            $options += array('rel' => 'last');

            if($params['page'] == $params['pageCount']){
                $out = $before . $this->Html->tag(
                    $tag, $last, compact('class')
                );
            }else{          
                $out = $before . $this->Html->tag(
                    $tag, $this->link($last, array('page' => $params['pageCount']), $options), compact('class')
                );
            }
        }
        return $out;
    }
}
```

Just override the function first and last by change in the original function of file `lib\Cake\View\Helper\PaginatorHelper.php`

You can use this helper like as below

```
<div class="paging">
<?php
    echo $this->PaginatorExt->first('<<', array('class' => 'first'));
    echo $this->PaginatorExt->prev('<', array(), null, array('class' => 'prev disabled'));
    echo '<span class="numbers">';
    echo $this->PaginatorExt->numbers();
    echo '</span>';
    echo $this->PaginatorExt->next('>', array(), null, array('class' => 'next disabled'));
    echo $this->PaginatorExt->last('>>', array('class' => 'last'));
?>
</div>
```

It is working for me.